# Reproducing the blocked exe "unblock" option in file properties in windows 2003

Tags: security, windows-server-2003, nsis

When I download my program from my website to my windows 2003 machine, it has a block on it and you have to right click on the exe, then properties, then select the button "Unblock".

I would like to add detection in my installer for when the file is blocked and hence doesn't have enough permissions.

But I can't eaisly reproduce getting my exe in this state where it needs to be unblocked.

How can I get the unblock to appear on my exe so I can test this functionality?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is done using NTFS File Streams. There is a stream named "Zone.Identifier" added to downloaded files. When IE7 downloads certain types of file that stream contains:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

The simplest way to set it is to create a text file with those contents in it, and use more to add it to the alternate stream.

Zone.Identifier.txt:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

Command:

```
more Zone.Identifier.txt > file.exe:Zone.Identifier
```

Then, the way for you to check it would be to try to open the Zone.Identifier stream and look for ZoneId=3, or simply assume that if the stream exists at all that your user will receive that warning.

It's also important to note that this has nothing to do with permissions. Administrators see the same warning; it's to do entirely with the source and type of file. The entire stream goes away when users uncheck the "Always ask before opening this file" box and then click Run.

Answer (score 11):

There is a supported API for this, documented on MSDN. Search on MSDN for "Persistent Zone Identifier Object". Basically you `CoCreateInstance` with `CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier` and request an `IPersistFile` interface. You then call `IPersistFile::Load` with the name of the file in question. Next, QI for an `IZoneIdentifier` interface and use `IZoneIdentifier::GetId` to obtain the zone of the file. If there was no "mark of the web", you should get `URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE`. The ZoneId of 3 mentioned in the other reply is `URLZONE_INTERNET`. (The enumeration is called `URLZONE` and is also documented on MSDN, or see `sdk\inc\urlmon.h`.) You can remove or change the "mark of the web" by calling `IZoneIdentifier::Remove` or `IZoneIdentifier::SetId` and then call `IPersistFile::Save`. There are more details about all of this on MSDN. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this it helped me a lot.

You can make the process even easier if you create a batch file with the contents.

```
echo [ZoneTransfer] > Zone.Identifier
echo ZoneId=3 >> Zone.Identifier
more Zone.Identifier > %1:Zone.Identifier
```

This will generate the Zone.Identifier for you and mark the file accordingly.

To run it just supply the file name e.g. if the file is called mark.bat

```
mark.bat myfile.txt
```