# How to check if a file has the win2003 "blocked" option on it

Tags: security, windows-server-2003, nsis

How do I check from within my NSIS installer if my installer has the blocked option in preferences on it.

Even if you know of a way to check this without NSIS, please let me know so I can script it myself.

See this question to find out [more info about this blocked option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135600/reproducing-the-blocked-exe-unblock-option-in-file-properties-in-windows-2003).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Hitscan's related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135600/reproducing-the-blocked-exe-unblock-option-in-file-properties-in-windows-2003)...

You can check if an EXE has this property simply by checking for the existance of the alternate data stream (ADS):

```
file.exe:Zone.Identifier
```