# How does Windows know if a file was downloaded from the Internet?

Tags: windows, file, google-chrome, download

If I open a file in Windows, that was downloaded by chrome or another browser Windows popups a warning, that this file is downloaded from the internet. The same for documents you open in Microsoft Word.

But how does windows know that this file originate from the Internet? I think it's the same file as every other file on my hard drive. Has it to do something with the file properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reproducing the blocked exe "unblock" option in file properties in windows 2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135600/reproducing-the-blocked-exe-unblock-option-in-file-properties-in-windows-2003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry Johnston got it!
Had nothing to do with temporary folder or media cache. It's a NTFS Stream.
For further reading: [MSDN File Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This blocking information is archieved with the following commands on the CLI:

```
(echo [ZoneTransfer]
More? echo ZoneId=3) > test.docx:Zone.Identifier
```

This creates an alternative file stream.

Answer (score -1):

When you download any file from internet. It first downloaded in Media Cache instead of temp folder. Only after that it moves to actual location where you select to save that file.
If you copy and paste some file then it move that file through Temp folder only. Before opening any file windows check the location and if it is Media Folder then you get the error "File is downloading or other errors related to this".

Comment: No, Windows didn't show any errors. It had said only that the file came from the internet, so it asks me to open it in "protected mode" (Microsoft Word). Media Cache means temp folder?

Comment: media cache folder is separate folder for browser downloads. Temp folder is responsible for any shifting of data.